# Modal popup after contact form submit

Tags: php, html, css

I have a simple website, index.php within the code of this page, there are three modals, a 'what we do' and a 'contact' which are triggered by buttons, and work as expected. 
'Contact' is a simple contact form, this works in so far as enter your details, and click submit. I used code I found online, `form-to-email.php` which validates and sends an email to me, so that all works fine.

What I am trying to do is once you click submit, it redirects you back to the `index.php` and opens the last modal, which is id'd as 'thankModal'. Now getting it to open the `index.php` is no problem using this command:

`header('Location: ../index.php');`

And I have tried various ways to get this to work and so far no success. I have spent a couple of days googling various things and so far it eludes me.

I presume it is probably something simple like appending the modal name to the end of the header code? I tried that but am unsure of the exact way to structure that.

Comment: Welcome, Karl! Please show the attempt you made in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With only a textual description of your website, it's really hard to guess what is going on. Also, be sure to output [PHP's errors and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display), and show them in the question, if any.

Comment: There is an easy way to do if your thankModal is PHP code, just add ?submit=true to the end of your header('Location: ../index.php'); like : header('Location: ../index.php?submit=true'); and at the beggining of your thankModal add this line of code : if (isset($_GET['submit']) && $_GET['submit' === true]) { // Your thakModal code here } However this is not a good solution, because if your user refresh that page, they will see that popup again and again !